# Get Visual Studio Extension to only operate with specific file types

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mef, visual-studio-extensions, file-type

I'm creating a pretty simple extension for visual studio. I'm trying to make the extension only active when working with a python file type. I found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372313(v=vs.120).aspx) and have tried to apply it to my situation but I think I'm missing something. The extension works properly with python files but also remains active with other file types when I'd like it to ignore them.

So far, I followed the walkthrough and made this class:

```
static class FileAndContentTypeDefinitions
{
    [Export]
    [Name("py")]
    [BaseDefinition("text")]
    internal static ContentTypeDefinition hidingContentTypeDefinition;

    [Export]
    [FileExtension(".py")]
    [ContentType("py")]
    internal static FileExtensionToContentTypeDefinition hiddenFileExtensionDefinition;

}
```

Then, in the SourceProvider and HandlerProvider I have:

```
[Export]
[ContentType("py")]
```

This enables the python file types to work but does not disable the extension when other file types are open. Is there a way for this to be accomplished?

EDIT: I realize that this is too ambiguous. The extension provides a completion suggestion for python doc comments based off of a method signature occurring the line before (if applicable). This is triggered when ''' is typed. I want this to only happen in python files.

The other exports are:
From HandlerProvider

```
[Export]
[ContentType("py")]

[Export(typeof(IVsTextViewCreationListener))]
[Name("token completion handler")]
[ContentType("text")]
[TextViewRole(PredefinedTextViewRoles.Editable)]
```

From Source Provider

```
[Export]
[ContentType("py")]

[Export(typeof(ICompletionSourceProvider))]
[ContentType("text")]
[Name("token completion")]
```

Might I also add that I followed the MSDN walkthroughs pretty closely since this is my first foray into extension creation. As a result though, I'm not confident I can explain every bit of the code (translation: I don't know what a lot of it does).

Comment: What do you mean by "disable the extension"? What are you trying to prevent?

Comment: Ah good point. So the extension provides a completion for python doc comments, triggering when ''' is typed. I want this to only happen in python files.

Comment: Please show us your exported services.

Comment: Hi @SLaks I just updated my question. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You're exporting your providers & listeners for *both* `[ContentType("text")]` and `[ContentType("py")]`.

Don't do that.

Also, your second `[Export]` attribute will export as that class itself, which is useless.

Comment: Can you expand a little on your second statement? Which second export? Do you mean both?

Comment: I mean the one that doesn't specify an interface that VS imports.

Comment: Tried to just declare [ContentType("py")] and remove the extra export calls. Nothing happens when I type ''' now. Probably some other issue elsewhere but for now I need to add them back to restore functionality.

Comment: @IanPanzica: Show me your current exports.

Comment: They're the same as I listed in the question now. I tried removing both empty [Export] statments as well as  setting ContentType to "py" (the combination and each exclusively) and in all cases, the completion suggestion was not occurring. So for now, the exports are back to how they were. On a related note, I don't understand how changing the ContentType to "py" from "text" would have broken it since the basedefinition of "py" is "text"

Comment: @IanPanzica: `text` is the base content type for all editors.  That's why it was showing up where you didn't want it.  Install https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ab39a092-1343-46e2-b0f1-6a3f91155aa6 in your dev instance and make sure your editor really has the right Content type.  Also set a breakpoint in your provider to see if it is created at all.

Comment: I can't install the extension because I'm using VS2013. My FileAndContentTypeDefinitions class is never being used (verified though breakpoints).

Comment: `FileAndContentTypeDefinitions` has no executable code in the first place.  Set breakpoints in your exported services.

Comment: If you download that VSIX, open it in a ZIP editor, and add v12 to the supported versions, it will probably work.  (but you'll need https://github.com/SLaks/Root-VSIX to install it)

Comment: I did. The SourceProvider and HandlerProvider are both used.

Comment: If they are being created, you have a bug somewhere else.  Debug through your code & see what's failing